# how to use time in C++

Tags: c++, time

I am a beginner in programming and I started to create a game in C++ where the player disappears from the screen(he dies) when a rock hits it.

What can i do to put the player back on the screen after 2 seconds?

I have number of lifes(LifeNb) a function which delete the player from the screen(removePlayer) and a function that add the player on the screen(addPlayer).
How can i do this using ?

```
int time = std::clock()/1000;
if(the rock hit) {
   number of lives --;
   remove player;
    if(time == 2)
      add   player;
}
```

It's something like this?

Comment: Does other stuff happen while the player is dead? If not you could just use `sleep(2);`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:  When your player dies, store the current time (plus two seconds) to a variable.  On each iteration of the game's event loop, check to see if the current time is greater than or equal to the time in the variable.  If it is, restore the player, and set the variable's value to (a very large value that the clock will never reach).

Comment: I want to use time.h because i want to put it immediately on the screen ,on the same place but after some seconds i will be sure that the rock will not be in the same place to hit the player again

Comment: Go ahead and use time.h then.

Answer (score 1):

```
clock_t timer = clock();
if ((clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)-(timer/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) >= 2)
    player.add();
```

If you just want to wait two seconds, however, you could also use the system library function `sleep()` for two seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The sleep() function will delay for a specified number of seconds before continuing execution.  It seems to be what you are looking for.

See here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/sleep.html